# Is ionic-cli support build with shared mode crosswalk?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

It seems crosswalk-cordova-android had implement [shared mode](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-cordova-android/pull/160). How I enable ionic-cli to build with shared mode crosswalk? Thanks.

Nb: I have ask this question on [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/288), but still not respond so far.

Answer (score 0):

ionic cli just calls cordova cli when you want to run commands like run, build, plugin... that are actually cordova commands.

A ionic project is a cordova project with some additions.

So what you have to do is follow [the steps to migrate a cordova project to a crosswalk-cordova project](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/migrate_an_application.html)

Unfortunatly they don't talk yet about shared mode in the migration wiki and I don't think it's supported by current released build.